# How to filter a child object's parent field for Django

Tags: python, django

I want to have a form with fields that are filtered based on Django group model name field.
For example, I have a model that is connected to Django User model which is connected to Django group model like so:

```
class customUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

I have added a row of data in Django group using Django admin panel called 'Teacher'.
What I'm trying to do is to have my form list only customUser that is listed as "Teacher" in Django group model.

My form:

```
class myForm(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = customUser
    fields = ['user ']

  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super (myForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        **# What I want to achieve but doesnt work.**
        self.fields['user'].queryset = customUser.objects.filter(user.group.name = "Teacher")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
customUser.objects.filter(user__groups__name='Teacher')
```

Check documentation about [Lookup reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/lookups/#lookup-reference)

Comment: @adqwqx. Did you have enough time to test the solution? Is it what you expect?